# Should we always use a comma before "especially"?

Tags: commas

I was reading an English grammar book in which I found:

> Roll down: to move something **down especially** by turning a handle.

In the bold part, I believe a comma is missing. But I am not sure whether this is intentional. Can you explain?

Answer (score 2):

A comma is used before *especially* when *especially* is used to set off a parenthetical clause, usually at the end of a sentence. See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/77046/93377) ELU answer.

No comma is used when *especially* is not being used to set off a parenthetical clause. Example:

> That was an especially fine performance.

Comment: "No comma is used when especially is used as an adverb." What else can it be used as? Do you have an example? Isn't "especially by turning a handle" a parenthetical phrase placed at the end of the definition?

Comment: @Rompey - You're right; "especially" is always an adverb. I have edited my answer.

Comment: To have it done with, should a comma be placed  before "especially" in the definition?